# New Install of Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on MacBook Pro (2010) won't restart, black screen with "Oops"

Tags: boot, system-installation, 18.04, macbook, gdm

I've recently installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on my macbookpro (2010). I've managed to go through the installation and set up it. However after first restart, I get a black screen of code that eventually freezes.

I've tried reinstalling but always get this screen after first restart.

[image: screen shot of black screen of code]

Comment: I have pretty much the exact same issue. Some answers on my post [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1049998/stuck-on-black-screen-with-text-after-installation-on-macbook-pro-2010/)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, the workaround I found was the following.

1. Use the live USB of ubuntu to access the PC then mount the HD where you installed Ubuntu, then:

   ```
    sudo vi mountinglocation/etc/default/grub
   ```
2. Edit the line containing `quiet splash` with `nomodeset`.
3. Reboot then at the GRUB menu press <kbd>e</kbd> and replace the `quiet splash` with `nomodeset`.
4. When you login the first time remember to update the GRUB settings with:

   ```
   sudo update-grub
   ```