# Stuck on black screen with text after installation on Macbook Pro 2010

Tags: boot, system-installation, 18.04, macbook

An install of just Ubuntu 18.04 LTS fails.

I used "nomodeset", for I get no visuals otherwise.

Installation is smooth for most of the time, but when it restarts, it just loops on this black screen with a ton of white text and codes. At some point it loops with the same text, the screen blinks (as if it tries to move forward), but just loops the same text.

I suspect it may be stuck on the logo splash screen, since I didn't a black screen with text on my PC at all when installing there, just on my MacBook.

Erasing the disk before install fails. 
Installing alongside another Ubuntu install fails.

Could it be the GPU driver?

Is my MacBook not supported by 18.04?

**EDIT:** 
By console, do you mean grub? Yes i can press esc on bootup and get to grub. CTRL + alt + f3 does nothing for me, but i can get to tty1 when booting the live USB by setting boot parameters to "splash 3".

I get a GUI when booting to USB and installing, and it finishes the install just fine. It's when rebooting after i get stuck on a console spamming the same things, and i can't make out which lines are error codes and which are not, so i don't know what to post here.

I made the USB using rufus in Windows 10.
xsession-error logs? How do i access that? with grub?
Please remember i know very little about how linux works, so some sort of tutorial or explanation would be greatly appreciated :)

model is a Macbook Pro 13" mid 2010, aka. macbookpro 7,1.
2.4 GHz Intel Core 2 Duo processor (P8600)
6 GB 1066mhz RAM
128GB aftermarket SSD

After rebooting it alternates between these two.
[image: console 1]
[image: console 2]

**EDIT 2**
Now i got this
[image: console 3]

**EDIT 3** 
So i managed to install 16.04. I'll stick with that until someone kindly suggests a solution to my problem, and i'll try to upgrade when they allow it late july :)  thanks for the help anyway!

Comment: Welcome **kashav** to askubuntu! Your post is very long with very less information. Please keep as short as possible in your question. Please post any error  **text** you get . Further, can you open a tty by using the key-combination Ctrl+Alt+F3 ?

Comment: When adding requested information, please click on the grey edit link above and to the left, then add it to the original post.

Comment: Did you make a bootable USB from the desktop installation image for installation? If you can get GUI using t he live CD, it means that you should be able to install Ubuntu on your macbook pro. Be patient, but do include all the details when asking in the forum. E.g., the year and model of your macbook pro, whether you have access to the console to get the xsession error log, etc. (Edit and add them to your original question.)

Comment: Updated post with answers and pictures